# A LCH space is $\sigma$-compact iff there is a strictly positive function in $C_0(E)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Show that a locally compact Hausdorff space $E$ is $\sigma$-compact if and only if there exists a strictly positive function in $C_0(E)$.

This is an exercise from Bauer's Measure and Integration Theory Section 29. I've shown the "if" part, but have difficulty with the 
"only if" part. I think I should use the following Lemma.

29.8 Lemma. Let $E$ be a LCH $\sigma-$compact space. Then $E$ can be covered by a sequence $(L_n)$ of compact subsets each contained in the interior of its successor. Also, an equivalent characterization of an $C_0(E)$ function is the function is continuous on the one-point compactification $E'=\{\omega_0\}\cup E$ with $f'(\omega_0)=0$ and $f'(x)=f(x)$ on $x\in E$. However, I don't know how to explicitly construct a continuous function from these $L_n$s given. My guess is they should have some property like $f\ge 1/n$ on each $L_n$. How can I prove this statement?

Comment: Urysohn's lemma is a good way to construct functions

Comment: Given one of the compacts $L_n$, can you ensure the existence of a continuous function function $f_n$ on $E'$ such that it is equal to $1$ on $L_n$ and $0$ at $\omega_0$ and is always between (0,1)? Once you have those sum them $\sum_n f_n/2^n$.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Ok so by Urysohn's lemma, we get $f_n$ that is $1$ on $L_n$ and has support inside $E$. Then by uniform convergence we get a continuous function on $E'$ by the sum you suggested that is $0$ at $\omega_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $E$ is a union of compact sets $K_n$, and consider the one-point compactification $E' = E \cup \{\infty\}$.

All $K_n$ are also closed in $E'$ and so we find $f_n: E' \to [0,1]$ such that
$f_n(\infty) = 0$ and $f[K_n] = \{1\}$, by Urysohn's lemma.

Then define $f: E' \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}f_n(x)$, which is well-defined and continuous. Then $f(\infty) = 0$ but if $x \in E$, $x \in K_m$ for some $m$ and then $f(x) \ge \frac{1}{2^m}f_m(x) = \frac{1}{2^m} > 0$, as all $f_n$ are positive and $f_m$ is $1$ on $K_m$. (this is essentially the proof of the fact that a closed $G_\delta$ in a  normal space, ( $\{\infty\}$ on $E'$ in this case) is a zero-set, i.e. of the form $g^{-1}[\{0\}]$ for a continuous real-valued $g$ on the set).
Then $f|E$ is a strictly positive continuous real function on $E$.